# datagridview specific condition checking

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a datagrid view. I want to match all the rows of datagrid view one by one with a specific value. My code is given below but it's not working:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVie.RowCount;i++ ){
    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "F7" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVie.RowCount;i++ ){
    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "F3" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVie.RowCount;i++ )
{
    if(  dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "T3" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVie.RowCount;i++ )
{
    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "C3" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave")
        count++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVie.RowCount;i++ ){
    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "T5" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;
}*/
/*for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVies.RowCount;i++ )
{
    if(  dataGridVies.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "O2" && dataGridVies.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;
}
/*for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVie.RowCount;i++ ){
    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "P2" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave")
        count++;
}*/
if(count==4)
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. give more information or provide an example

Answer (score -1):

```
    for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVie.RowCount;i++ ){
    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "F7" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;

    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "F3" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;

    if(  dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "T3" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;

    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "C3" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave")
        count++;

    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "T5" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;
}*/
/*for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVies.RowCount;i++ )
{
    if(  dataGridVies.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "O2" && dataGridVies.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave" )
        count++;
}
/*for(int i = 0; i < dataGridVie.RowCount;i++ ){
    if(dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim() == "P2" && dataGridVie.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "slow wave")
        count++;
}*/
if(count==4)
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

Comment: what answer is this? using a single loop is surely more efficient but it doesn't change the result. plus, you don't explain anything

Comment: you said  "I want to match all the rows of datagrid view one by one"  so what is the problem in this revised code.

Comment: your code is equivalent to his code, since count++ is declared outside the loop in both cases. so you're not solving any problem (problem that is still unclear)

Comment: add you grid sample data. and your desire output